# Conditional parsing and casting in Attoparsec

Tags: haskell, monads, parsec, attoparsec

I'm parsing a length-encoded binary stream and I'm trying to get this code compiling. The combinatorrent code ( https://github.com/jlouis/combinatorrent/blob/master/src/Protocol/Wire.hs ) was very helpful to get me moving along but now I'm stuck. How do I use the frame_length in the return statement?

```
data FrameCont = FINAL | MORE | BADCONT
    deriving (Show, Eq)
frame_cont 0x00      = FINAL
frame_cont 0x01      = MORE
frame_cont otherwise = BADCONT

data FrameSize = Small Word8 | Jumbo B.ByteString
    deriving (Show)

get_fc = do
    raw_cont <- AP.anyWord8
    guard((frame_cont raw_cont) /= BADCONT) AP.<?> "State must be either MORE or FINAL"
    return raw_cont

parser = do
    frame_length <- AP.anyWord8
    case frame_length of
        0x255      ->  return (Jumbo <$> AP.take 8, get_fc, AP.take (fromIntegral frame_length))
        otherwise  ->  return (Small otherwise, get_fc, AP.take (fromIntegral frame_length))
```

Also: how do I use pass (AP.take 8) into a Word64?

Comment: Without more context, we can only guess. What type should `parser` have? And what is it supposed to do? If I understand the last question correctly: you can convert an 8-byte ByteString, which you get from `AP.take 8`, to a `Word64` via `foldl' (\w b -> (shiftL w 8) .|. fromIntegral b) 0 . unpack`.

Comment: I have gone ahead and added more context. I have a type which encapsulates both Word8 and ByteString. I will want to change the bytestring to Word64 in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The first components of the two branches of parser have different types, the `Jumbo` branch's is a `Parser FrameSize`, the other a plain `FrameSize`. If `parser` should have the type `Parser (Parser FrameSize, Parser Word8, Parser ByteString)`, simply change the first component of the second branch to `return (Small otherwise)`. However, it seems more likely that you want `parser :: Parser (FrameSize, Word8, ByteString)`, so you have to run the other parsers inside `parser`. I think

```
parser = do
    frame_length <- AP.anyWord8
    frame_size <- case frame_length of
                    0xFF -> Jumbo <$> AP.take 8   -- 0xFF == 255, 0x255 == 597
                    flen -> return (Small flen)
    fc <- get_fc
    bs <- AP.take (fromIntegral frame_length)
    return (frame_size, fc, bs)
```

is at least close to what you want.

A note on style: You mix camelCase and underscore_separated words, better settle for one (the predominant style in Haskell is camelCase, so I advise choosing that).

Comment: He does have a pattern: capitalized words use CamelCase, lowercase words use_underscores. It's a bit unusual but it's not inconsistent.

Comment: Yes, it's consistent. At least in *his* code. But through the use of camelCased library functions, he gets a mixture of both styles. If he's not too fond of the underscores, I think it's better to conform to the dominant style.